# Google Script Pass Variable To Click Handler

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a Google Apps script and I have a question about passing a variable to the click handler. The script is published as a Web App and is accessed by an HTML link in an email (its an approve/deny form for a business request). When someone submits a form, an email is sent to the approver who when clicks on the approve link. This link contains the following variables:

`?status=enteredInCC&rowNum=9`

So when they click on the link the script is launched, and it enters the `function doGet(e)` block and where relevant code is:

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
var grid = app.createGrid(1, 2);
var label = app.createLabel('Please enter the item\'s PLU:')
var input = app.createTextBox().setId("input").setName("input");
grid.setWidget(0, 0, label);
grid.setWidget(0, 1, input);
var handler = app.createServerHandler("retrieveInput").addCallbackElement(input);
var button = app.createButton("OK", handler);
var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId("panel")
panel.add(grid);
panel.add(button);
app.add(panel);

return app;
```

Which leads to the click handler:

```
function retrieveInput(e){
  var input = e.parameter.input;
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var panel = app.getElementById('panel');

  panel.clear();

  app.add(app.createHTML('<h2>The request has been updated. You can close this window.</h2>'))
  app.close()
  return app;
}
```

And all of that runs great. However, earlier in the `doGet(e)` function some information was collected from the URL and stored in variables. Now in `retrieveInput(e)` I'm needing to access those variables to make some updates to the Spreadsheet (just after `panel.clear()`). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing in variables will not work because the `retrieveInput` function is called in a new/different "instance" of your script, therefore not being able to access variables set in the `doGet`. In your case, I suggest you save the desired parameters as hidden inputs in the `panel` and use it as `callbackElement` instead of only the `input`. Like this:

```js
function doGet(e) { 
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId("panel")
  panel.add(app.createHidden('status', e.parameter.status));
  panel.add(app.createHidden('rowNum', e.parameter.rowNum));
  var grid = app.createGrid(1, 2);
  var label = app.createLabel('Please enter the item\'s PLU:')
  var input = app.createTextBox().setId("input").setName("input");
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, label);
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, input);
  var handler = app.createServerHandler("retrieveInput")
    .addCallbackElement(panel); //changed to panel instead of input
  var button = app.createButton("OK", handler);
  panel.add(grid).add(button);
  return app.add(panel);
}
```

Then you can use `e.parameter.status` and others normally in `retrieveInput(e)`.